# How we can set the response header to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Is there any way to set the response header to ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*") in jQuery Ajax request, as I am not sure how to do that.. this is my below code.. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

```
var on_show_info = function() {

                request_info = $.ajax({
                url: search_metadata + current_doc_info.id,
                type: 'GET',
                async: true,
                success: on_metadata,
                error: on_metadata_error    
        });
    };

    var on_get_metadata= function(data, text_status, XMLHttpRequest) {

    alert("data");
        console.log(data);
        var html = "";
        var info = {};

        html = html + "<table border ='0'>";
        html= html + "<tr>";
        html =html + "<td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Item Location:</span> " +(data.response.docs[0].itemLocation)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Cycle: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].lifeCycle)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Revision: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].revision)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Timestamp: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].timestamp)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>ID: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].id)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Attachment: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].hasAttachment)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Description: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].description)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Change: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].changeNumber)+"</td></tr>";
        if(data.response.docs[0].distributionLevel==undefined)
        {
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Level: </span>Data Not Available</td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Distribution Level: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].distributionLevel)+"</td></tr>"; 
        }


        //html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>Renewal Due Date: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].c_renewal_due_date)+"</td></tr>";
        if(data.response.docs[0].asicBomSubdescriptor==undefined)
        {
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>descriptor: </span>Data Not Available</td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>descriptor: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].asicBomSubdescriptor)+"</td></tr>";

        }
        html =html + "<tr><td><span style='color:#8A8A8A'>LifeCycle: </span>" +(data.response.docs[0].lifeCycle)+"</td></tr>";
        html =html + "</table>";


        $('#popup-meta').removeClass('waiting');
        $('#popup-meta .popup-content').html(html);
    };

    var on_get_metadata_error = function(XMLHttpRequest, text_status, error) {
        alert("error");
        $('#popup-meta').removeClass('waiting');
        $('#popup-meta .popup-content').html('<span class="data-error">Unable to get meta data.</span>');
    };
```

Comment: are able to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t change the response header from client code, it comes from the **server**.

(You can of course change your request headers (see the jQuery docs for `ajax`), but that's not going to help here).

If you also have control over what your server sends, then by all means update your post accordingly (i.e. give details of platform / language etc.)

Comment: @Ben Poole, I am working on the server side. How can I resolve this issue. what do you need. As I have no clue to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't know what response and request headers are, you have no business building a web app, never mind working on the server too. For anyone to help you, you need to tell us **which technology you are using** (as I said in my response above).

Comment: @Ben Poole, I am using JSP and jQuery to make the ajax requests that I have written above in my question. Is there any way by using php to change the response header by putting some script in the javascript file.

Comment: OK, if you're using php, just use the `header()` function, as mentioned be genesis - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @Ben Poole, thanks for reply.. But I am not using PHP.. I am using jQuery to make the AJAX requests and in that jQuery that URL is there.. so is there any way to use php withing that javascript(jQuery)...or something that I can do in jQuery for the response header??

Comment: The only URL information I can see in your original post is this: `url: search_agile_metadata + current_doc_info.id` which doesn't really help. Are you posting to a JSP or PHP (you mention both)? Depending on which it is, you will need to configure the server or web application accordingly. JSP code can set response headers easily enough, as can PHP. Or you can configure the application / web server you're running to send appropriate headers. Either way, your client-side code and jQuery are irrelevant. **The change needs to happen on the server.**

Answer (score 2):

"Server response header" states for Server response header, not Client request header so YOU CAN'T CHANGE RESPONSE HEADER. You have to put it at the top of file you're retreiving from.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: thanks for reply... How can I use this in my javascript file where all jQuery is written to make the ajax requests.. If I am putting this at the top in my javascript file.. then its not working.. Any suggestions how should I put this..

Comment: You can't put PHP code into a client-side Javascript file. PHP is a server-side scripting language.

Comment: as @Ben said, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Those headers are for organization websites to communicate with each other. In other words, you have to control all the servers involved. Providing those headers simply relaxes the same-domain restriction for sites with different domain names all owned by the same individual or organization. It does *not* provide a mechanism for subverting same-domain restrictions with a 3rd-party.